# Store a variable in memory that can be get and modify for all users in web api netcore?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

In my web api, I need to store a list in memory that can be accessed by all users and each time, each user request to api, an object will be add to that list. I had defined that list in a static class but when i debug, each time user request, the list still the same value when first time defined.

**my static class:**

```
    public static class Images{
          private static List<string> _imageStorage = new List<string>(){img1, img2, img3};
          public static AddImageId(string id){
              _imageStorage.Add(id);      #It still 3 values when debug
          }
    }
```

Comment: The `List<T>` class is not thread safe. Are you sure it doesn't make more sense to store this information in a database?

Comment: do you have web garden ? (more process for the used pool)

Comment: @Aristos no I dont have a web garden

Comment: @mason because of performance, I dont want to store that in db. For my app purpose, it should be store in memory only.

Comment: Then you'll need to find a thread safe way of doing so.